# MySQL column values to array. Wrong values as a result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Trying to get all the values from a single column.
After all simply trying to print all the values to check if everything is OK. Unfortunately all the values I get printed are the same - "Array" (without quotes).

I am quite new working with MySQL. Here is my code:

```
$sql_connect = mysql_connect("localhost","db_user_name","db_password") ;
if (!$sql_connect) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die ("no database");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT column_name FROM table_name");
$video_IDs = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $video_IDs[] =  $row[$key];  
}
```

then, I print the `$video_IDs` array

```
$test = 1 ;
while (each($video_IDs)) {
    echo "{$test} - {$video_IDs}<br />" ;
    $test++ ;
}

mysql_close($sql_connect);
```

As a result i get printed all 10 values as 10 row are in my table. But all the values are "Array" (without quotes).

My result:

```
1 - Array
2 - Array
3 - Array
4 - Array
5 - Array
6 - Array
7 - Array
8 - Array
9 - Array
10 - Array
```

Looking forward to get any suggestions.

Comment: You are printing the object itself, try accessing it by index, something like `$video_IDS[index]`. Also, you could avoid looping through that twice.

Comment: Also, this is old code. We don't do this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native way to `echo` an array without using a loop or recursion or accessing a specific element of said array. You're using the `each` function improperly as well since it returns a key/value pair as a result (and you're not capturing that result for the loop.) You should do something like this instead:

```
$test = 1 ;
foreach ($video_IDs as $v) {
    echo "{$test} - {$v}<br />";
    $test++;
}
```

If you must use `each`, here's a slight change to your original code so that the key/value pair is stored in `$v` over every iteration

```
$test = 1 ;
while ($v = each($video_IDs)) {
    echo "{$test} - {".$v['value']."}<br />" ;
    $test++ ;
}
```

If you're just trying to display the array without any specific formatting, use `var_dump` or `print_r`

It is also necessary to note that you're using a depreciated function (`mysql_*`) and you should use MySQLi or PDO for your SQL queries.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions and pointing the depreciated function (mysql_*). I have changed the connection to MySQL DB functions and everything else and now i have a proper results.

Answer (score 0):

If `$video_IDs` is an array, you need to use [print_r](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or loop through each element.  The code below will output the data you are

```
$test = 1 ;
foreach( $video_IDs as $key => $value) {
  if( is_array($value) ){
    echo "$test $key =>";
    print_r($value);
    echo "<br/>";
  }else{
     echo "$test $key => $value <br/>";
  }
   $test++ ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print array content then use print_r(array_name)
Best way to see the content is

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_name);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

## **Solution found**

Thank you for suggestions and pointing the depreciated function (mysql_*). I have changed the connection to MySQL DB functions and everything else and now i have a proper results.

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db_name'); 

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT column_name FROM table_name";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

while ($video_IDs = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
 $rows[] = $video_IDs ;
}

foreach($rows as $video_IDs)
{
 echo $video_IDs['column_name']."<br />";
}
```

Thank you all for comments!